# Java override abstract generic method

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, custom-attributes

**I have the following code**

```
public abstract class Event {
    public void fire(Object... args) {
        // tell the event handler that if there are free resources it should call 
        // doEventStuff(args)
    }

    // this is not correct, but I basically want to be able to define a generic 
    // return type and be able to pass generic arguments. (T... args) would also 
    // be ok
    public abstract <T, V> V doEventStuff(T args);
}

public class A extends Event {
   // This is what I want to do
   @Overide
   public String doEventStuff(String str) {
      if(str == "foo") { 
         return "bar";
      } else {
         return "fail";
      }
   }
}

somewhere() {
  EventHandler eh = new EventHandler();
  Event a = new A();
  eh.add(a);
  System.out.println(a.fire("foo")); //output is bar
}
```

However I don't know how to do this, as I cannot override `doEventStuff` with something specific.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Since the generic parameters don't appear anywhere else, the method signature is broadly equivalent to `public abstract Object doEventStuff(Object args)`.  It's a method which takes *anything* as an argument, and returns *something*.  Are you sure this is what you intended?  If not, you likely want to define the `T` and/or `V` parameters on the `Event` class, not just for the method.

Comment: Also, be aware that `if(str == "foo") { ` is probably wrong and you need something like `if("foo".equals(str)) { `

Comment: Thx for the "foo".equals... this would have messed lots of things up, if it went unnoticed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps you just need to make `Event` itself generic:

```
public abstract class Event<T, V>
{
    public abstract V doEventStuff(T args);
}

public class A extends Event<String, String>
{
    @Override public String doEventStuff(String str)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do :). This is realy easier then I thought. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

You're using generics but you are not providing a binding.

```
public abstract class Event<I, O> { // <-- I is input O is Output
  public abstract O doEventStuff(I args);
}

public class A extends Event<String, String> { // <-- binding in the impl.
  @Override
    public String doEventStuff(String str) {
  }
}
```

Or simpler with only one generic binding...

```
public abstract class Event<T> { // <-- only one provided
  public abstract T doEventStuff(T args);
}

public class A extends Event<String> { // <-- binding the impl.

  @Override
    public String doEventStuff(String str) {
  }
}
```